# Header alignment

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to display "Heading Here" in centre
and "left arrow " and "tick" should display left side of "header Here"

all should display proportionally within screen ?

1) "Heading here" is shifted to right , but it should display in centre

How i can do that? [screen attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmpeX.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/GreenheaderBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_arrow_back_white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_back_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick_white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_selection_on" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heading_here"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/avier_next_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Heading Here"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avier_next_regular"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sub heading here"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your xml here ?

Comment: Share your xml code

Comment: provide xml for that

Comment: It's not `Heading here` shifted to right but it's your `sub heading here` shifted to left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your layout to relative layout so the header text can expand to the full width of the layout. I have converted the layout to relative. Please change the color and icon as it will give issues as i am using my color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_shade"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_arrow_back_white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick_white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_arrow_back_white"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_white" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heading_here"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_next_medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Heading Here"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_next_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sub heading here"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```